# React Redux Typescript vs React Redux Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I am starting to learn react with redux which should I focus on react redux with typescript or react redux java script

Comment: Wrong place to ask such a broad question unfortunately. I'll try to answer it anyway: it depends on what you know already. Do you have prior React experience?

Comment: Start with JavaScript. When you're comfortable with JS, switch to TypeScript (which is JavaScript with types and stuff).

Comment: I know java script as well as typescript but dont have enterprise application experience in it

Comment: so asking for that like will choosing one or other will bite me later in development

Comment: if you plan to get a job later, i suggest get to know typescript, if you know javascript then its not too early to start learning TS, just rememeber :any is your friend at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know TypeScript like you are writing, use TypeScript.

Knowledge you acquire this way can be used with or without TypeScript - and you get nice editor support for free.

Go by the official [Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) and read the [TypeScript QuickStart](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start) guide that will show you most of what you need to know for TS+Redux